# Scrapyd: How to specify libs and common folders that deployed projects can use?

Tags: python, scrapyd

Scrapyd is service where we can eggify deploy our projects. However I am facing a problem. I have a Project named MyScrapers whose spider classes uses an import statement as follows:

`from mylibs.common.my_base_spider import MyBaseSpider`

The path to my_base_spider is `/home/myprojectset/mylibs/common/my_base_spider`

While setting environment variable `PYTHONPATH=$HOME/myprojectset/`, I am able to run MyScrapers using scrapy command: scrapy crawl MyScrapers.

But when I use scrapyd for deploying MyScrapers by following command: scrapy deploy scrapyd2 -p MyScrapers, I get the following error:

**Server response (200):
{"status": "error", "message": "ImportError: No module named mylibs.common.my_base_spider"}**

Please tell how to make  deployed project to use these libs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer by adding `mylibs` to `site-packages` of python by using `setup.py` inside `mylib` folder. That way I could import everything inside `mylib` in my projects. Actually `mylibs` were way outside from the location where `setup.py` of my deploy-able project is present. `setup.py` looks for packages on same level and inside the folders where it is located.

Answer (score 1):

You need to edit your `setup.py` and/or `MANIFEST.in` to declare that it has a `mylibs` package dependency.

See [the distutils documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/distutils/sourcedist.html) for more information.

Comment: Any idea about this error? {"status": "error", "message": "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'module_name'"}

Comment: For your info, here is my directory structure for MyScrapers' setup.py: /home/myprojectset/scrapy_projects/MyScrapers/setup.py                 and Here is path to mylibs: /home/myprojectset/scrapy_projects/mylibs/   how would I add mylibs to setup.py?

Comment: Which means, my libs is outside my project. So, it cannot be deployed as an egg. But I need to use it in imports. Please response ASAP.

Comment: Did you read the link? Did you try changing the `packages` argument? We can't tell you *exactly* what to do because you haven't shown us your `setup.py` and we can't replicate your build environment exactly, but the basic answer is the same--you need to declare the dependency. Once you do it will be bundled into the egg.

Comment: Actually `mylibs` were way outside from the location where `setup.py` of my deploy-able project is present. I tried giving full paths to `mylibs` in `packages` property of `setup.py` but that didn't solve my problem. I found the answer by adding `mylibs` to `site-packages` of python by using `setup.py` inside `mylib` folder. That way I could import everything inside `mylib` in my projects.

Comment: What you have done is create a separate `mylibs` distribution with the `mylibs` package in it. This is a solution, but it's not the same as making the `mylibs` package part of your scrapy project's distribution. In either case, you still need to make sure `mylibs` is declared as a dependency so that when you one day need to say `easy_install my_scrapy_project`, it will download and install `mylibs` as well. You should add what you did as an answer here for future visitors.

Comment: Yes, I have added it as an answer. Thanks for providing help. :)